# changing jquery datepicker settings has no effect

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Depending on the selected date, I'd like modify the image used to launch the datepicker.
In the onSelect event I set the inst.settings.buttonImage property but the image doesn't change. The next time I launch the datepicker and check the property in the onSelect event, it is indeed set to the new image.  What do I have to do to make the new property take effect.

Comment: Have you tried using the setter: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonImage rather than altering the settings property itself?

Comment: Yes and that method works. I used $("#" + inst.id).datepicker( "option", "buttonImage", "images/redCalendar.png" ); I still don't understand why my original method failed

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe the setter method also forces a redraw, that a simple property change doesn't...